# want to split sql column data as below mention

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column `coordinate`, with many comma separated coordinates.
Now I want to split this coordinates.
example: If i have coordinate like

```
20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,
```

Then I want only 1st coordinate like

```
log:20.45847832 lat:73.99704207
```

Comment: Putting multiple values into a single cell is a *bad* idea, breaking even the most fudamental design rule. You should probably fix the design first and store different coordinates into different rows.

Comment: That said, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2016 and later to split fist by `,`, then by `-`

Comment: BTW what does this represent? SQL Server has spatial types and functions, including the ability to parse WKT representations. If this is represents a MULTIPOINT or LINESTRING, you could use string replacements to turn it into eg `MULTIPOINT ( 20.45847832 73.99704207,20.45868114 73.99712939)` before parsing it with [geography::Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/parse-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

Comment: Getting the first point can be done in a one-liner `geography::Parse('MULTIPOINT (' + replace(@string,'-', ' ') +')')
                                   .STPointN(1)`. After that, it depends on how you want to use the point. ADO.NET supports spatial types so you could return it directly to the client. Or you could use other spatial functions to calculate eg distances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for adding a third answer, but this is - again - a completely new approach.

If you need the first pair of coordinates in the format you state in your question, this is a real onliner:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(1000)='20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,';

SELECT 'log:' + STUFF(LEFT(@YourString,PATINDEX('%,%',@YourString)-1),PATINDEX('%-%',@YourString),1,' lat:');
```

The result

```
log:20.45847832 lat:73.99704207
```

### UPDATE according to your comments

Try this

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(tagdata VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,');

SELECT FirstPair
      ,LEFT(FirstPair,PATINDEX('%-%',FirstPair)-1) AS lon
      ,SUBSTRING(FirstPair,PATINDEX('%-%',FirstPair)+1,1000) AS lat
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEFT(tagdata,PATINDEX('%,%',tagdata)-1)) A(FirstPair);
```

Comment: I have multiple rows for this column.  select coordinates from tagdata and it should create 2 column after split

Comment: @RahulDhandePatil, Just add `FROM SomeTable` and replace the `@YourString` with the actual column name.

Comment: DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(1000)=(select coordinates from tagdata);

SELECT 'log:' + STUFF(LEFT(coordinates,PATINDEX('%,%',coordinates)-1),PATINDEX('%-%',coordinates),1,' lat:');

Comment: @RahulDhandePatil, Sorry, but it is really essential information to tell us, where this string comes from and how the output should look like. Please do not add such information in comments. Use the edit-option to re-enter your question and add this there.

Comment: its just a demo i share not actual data

Comment: @RahulDhandePatil, but you must share the actual structure and - most important  - the actual output-format. Your *log:20.45847832 lat:73.99704207* looks like a string in one line...

Comment: yes.
this answer you given is work fine for single. but for multiple (for select query) it gives error

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server 2016 and above, you can use STRING_SPLIT function. If I understand correctly, you only want to get the first coordinate among the given coordinate. The idea is to split by ',' then substring it by '-'. After that, you can select the record as much as you want. Hope this answer your question.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX) = '20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,'

SELECT TOP 1 'Log:' + ColumnLog + ' Lat:' + ColumnLat AS Coordinate
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(VALUE, 1, CHARINDEX('-', VALUE)-1) AS ColumnLog,
        SUBSTRING(VALUE, CHARINDEX('-', VALUE) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', VALUE)-1) AS ColumnLat
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var, ',') WHERE RTRIM(VALUE) <> ''
) X
```

Comment: I vote this up, as the accepted answer is very close to yours and the OP does not yet have the right to vote... The question was very unclear... Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Do not store such values in a CSV-list. This is breaking 1.NF and is a really bad design. Use this code to repair your design and store these coordinates in a related side-table. Try to use the [GEOGRAPHY abilites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017), introduced in SQL-Server-2008.

You can get this in one single action:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(1000)='20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,';

WITH Casted(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,',','</y></x><x><y>'),'-','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)
          .query('/x[y/text()]')
)
SELECT * FROM Casted;
```

The result

```
<x>
  <y>20.45847832</y>
  <y>73.99704207</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45868114</y>
  <y>73.99712939</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45849913</y>
  <y>73.99750285</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45831804</y>
  <y>73.99736981</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45848571</y>
  <y>73.99702964</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45851507</y>
  <y>73.99715704</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45852753</y>
  <y>73.99720817</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>20.45849614</y>
  <y>73.99728646</y>
</x>
```

Use this within an `XQuery/Xpath` like here:

```
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,',','</y></x><x><y>'),'-','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)
          .query('/x[y/text()]') AS AsXml
)
SELECT x.value('y[1]/text()[1]','decimal(12,8)') AS [log]
      ,x.value('y[2]/text()[1]','decimal(12,8)') AS [lat]
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') A(x);
```

And you get

```
log         lat
20.45847832 73.99704207
20.45868114 73.99712939
20.45849913 73.99750285
20.45831804 73.99736981
20.45848571 73.99702964
20.45851507 73.99715704
20.45852753 73.99720817
20.45849614 73.99728646
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this as a new answer, as it follows a completely different approach: With SQL-Server-2016+ you can use `JSON` abilities:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(1000)='20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646,';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON('[{"lon":"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,',','"},{"lon":"'),'-','","lat":"') + '"}]')
WITH(lon float '$.lon'
    ,lat float '$.lat');
```

The result

```
lon         lat
20,45847832 73,99704207
20,45868114 73,99712939
20,45849913 73,99750285
20,45831804 73,99736981
20,45848571 73,99702964
20,45851507 73,99715704
20,45852753 73,99720817
20,45849614 73,99728646
0           NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports [spatial data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). You could treat this string as a [MULTIPOINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/multipoint?view=sql-server-2017), parse it and return the first point in it, eg with:

```
declare @string nvarchar(200)='20.45847832-73.99704207,20.45868114-73.99712939,20.45849913-73.99750285,20.45831804-73.99736981,20.45848571-73.99702964,20.45851507-73.99715704,20.45852753-73.99720817,20.45849614-73.99728646'

declare @point geography=geography::Parse('MULTIPOINT (' + replace(@string,'-', ' ') +')')
                                   .STPointN(1)

select @point.Lat,@point.Long
```

`'MULTIPOINT (' + replace(@string,'-', ' ') +')'` replaces the `-` with a space and creates a string that can be parsed as a [multipoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/multipoint?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
MULTIPOINT (20.45847832 73.99704207,20.45868114 73.99712939,20.45849913 73.99750285,20.45831804 73.99736981,20.45848571 73.99702964,20.45851507 73.99715704,20.45852753 73.99720817,20.45849614 73.99728646)
```

[geography::Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/parse-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) can parse the Well-Known-Text representation of a spatial feature and return the feature itself as a [geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017) object.

After that. [STPointN(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stpointn-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) returns the first point in the multipoint. The coordinates are available through the Lat and Long properties

ADO.NET supports spatial types through the Microsoft.Sql.Types library. `geography` objects are returned as [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) instances